# Minimum Size for a valid APK File

Tags: android, file, apk

Is it possible to say what the minimal size in byte for a valid APK file would be? It should be installable on android but does not need to have any function at all. All Strings could be conserned as 1 char long (8byte).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to my new project with predefined application name, its size is 35k.

update:
After removing all useless texts and images (i just kept 1 ldpi image as icon with size of 2.66k) and compiling new apk file its size reduced to 7KB.

Comment: but is when i just do a new project e.g. in ecplise really the bare bone of an android application?

Comment: i just updated my answer. the first 35k is eclipse generated project with some predefined text and 4 images as launcher icon for ldpi, mdpi, hdpi and xhdpi. however, i removed all unnecessary items and just kept smaller image as icon.

Answer (score 0):

There is no minimum size for the APK file. You can add apk files up to 4GB.

Comment: my estimatations are not for the play store :) and the play store only accept apk files up to 50MB but extra files with whatever else extension up to 4GB. A APK could of course be as big as you want (with limitations of your filesytem of course) but because its just a zip file it doesent matter.

Answer (score 0):

```
Android app store minimum size of apk is :- 7 KB 

Android app store maximum size of apk is :- 100 MB

Google Play Store increases Android APK Size Limit from 50MB to 100MB. 
Google is doubling the maximum APK file size on the Play Store from 50 MB to 100 MB. 
Android app developers can now build higher quality Apps and Games that users love.
```